# Ruby 2.4 on Mac OS Mojave : image not found ... related to openssl.bundle

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rbenv

So i upgraded my Ruby to 2.4.9 on Mac OS Mojave.

I'm having trouble gem-installing...

```
    proj$ gem install google-cloud-vision
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/Users/mc/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mc/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/mc/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

proj$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

I already did a bunch of brew update && brew upgrade, but i'm stuck... any pointers?

Comment: Remove Ruby and reinstall.

Comment: ...including versions stored using `rbenv`.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the comment: Remove Ruby and reinstall.

Comment: That did work. I removed my ~/.rbenv and did a bund linstall after that