# Getting an weird error trying to install Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

Ruby is installed

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.4p301 (2017-03-30 revision 58214) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

and trying to run the command

```
> sudo gem install rails


Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gem-wrappers-1.4.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the error message, but have you `brew install openssl` or whatever it is these days?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby 2.4 on Mac OS Mojave : image not found ... related to openssl.bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997332/ruby-2-4-on-mac-os-mojave-image-not-found-related-to-openssl-bundle)

Comment: Older ruby versions must be built with an older version of OpenSSL, which you might not have installed currently. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511943/troubles-with-rvm-and-openssl for possible solutions.

Comment: regarding this - would it be just easier to upgrade ruby then?

Comment: If you are starting something new, definitely. 2.3 went end-of-life in 2019, so 2.7 or 3.0 would be preferable. If you have an existing project, you would also need to consider upgrading the rails version as well, which can be non-trivial depending on the complexity of your application.